# JetBrains WebStorm/PyCharm auto format JSX conflicts with ESLint indents

Tags: pycharm, webstorm, jsx, eslint

To clarify:

- I'm using [PyCharm Professional](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/#web-development), which is a combo of PyCharm & WebStorm.
- I have already [applied](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/eslint.html) formatting rules from my ESLint to my PyCharm.

**My Problem**: My ESLint throws errors whenever I auto format my JSX code.

How ESLint wants it:

[image: Code Example with ESLint format]

What PyCharm auto-formats it to:

[image: Code Example with PyCharm auto format]

**How can I get PyCharm to format this correctly?**

I'm unsure what I need to change in my settings and it's not applying them through using the `Apply ESLint Code Style Rules` settings option.

*Additional info on my IDE:*

- PyCharm 2018.2.4 (Professional Edition)
- Build #PY-182.4505.26, built on September 19, 2018

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML | Other**, try disabling **Align attributes** - does it help?
Importing rules from `eslint-plugin-react` is not implemented, so HTML formatter preferences are not changed when applying ESLint code style rules. You have to configure them manually in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML**. 
Related feature request: [WEB-28857](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28857)

Comment: Thank you! Disabling the `Align attributes` option under HTML | Other successfully resolved the conflicting auto-format.